# RC PWM question - dimming LEDs

Tags: power, led, pwm, remote-control, dimming

I have some automotive LEDs that I put onto an RC car. I use the RC car's 4S LiPo (14.8v) to power the LEDs and they are great. I use a hobby PWM relay board to turn them on and off and that's slick; I just plug it into the receiver and its flips the load on and off.

But now I need to be able to **dim** the LEDs, so I need to vary the voltage going to them. (The LED modules have a control board on them to regulate the current based on the voltage, so when I adjust the voltage from a bench supply, they dim accordingly. The LEDs I'm using are rock lights for real off-road trucks and just get wired directly to the car's battery.)

I can't find any off-the-shelf tiny module (needs to fit on the small RC car) that will let me do this. I tried using a RC brushed speed control with little success. I was getting some irregular dimming and feedback into the receiver which made my steering servo jitter.

I'm not an EE (very light knowledge) but I need a way to dim these 12V DC lights remotely via my RC Futaba controller. I have several modules to dim and they pull about 1 amp all together. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking what module to buy? But what if the automotive LEDs are not dimmable, how do you know they are? Do you know how they are constructed, have you reverse-engineered them? Is there a manual that says they are dimmable?

Comment: Look up "rc pwm to voltage converter" and you'll find plenty of results on converting a radio control PWM signal (1 ms - 2 ms pulses at 50 Hz) into a variable DC voltage.

Comment: most truck lights have a power supply integrated so that 11v looks the same as 14.5v. You'll have to remove that an integrate your own constant current driver with the max voltage as to that of the LED array, then you can PWM that.

Comment: Found [one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/193756569124). It has REMOTE CONTROLLER, too. You may wire the receiver to  control points.

Comment: ah, good search term jms, thats the closest I've found, still its only doing 10v max.. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B06XCVY3GM/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A1OB26G8TSLEZQ&psc=1   I will keep looking!!!!

Comment: justme, no I have the modules already. I dont want to modify them. Dandavis, the modules have current limiting in them, voltage is used to control brightness. Jay, thats nice, but I need to use my rc controller for control (1 mile range).